# Use of PTPd on RedHat/CentOS

Tags: centos, redhat, linux-networking, timestamp, ptp

I need to create a reliable and accurate synchronization between two CentOS 6 machines connected through a direct Ethernet connection.

I've seen that on Linux several implementation of [the IEEE 1588 Precision Time Protocol (PTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) exist:

- [PTPd](http://ptpd.sourceforge.net):

  - Apparently, this is the original implentation
  - Apparently, [it is still maintained](http://www.github.com/ptpd/ptpd)
- [PTPd2](http://ptpd2.sourceforge.net):

  - A new version meant to supersede the previous implementation
  - Apparently unmaintained
  - For CentOS 6, available only in the EPEL repositories
- [PTPv2d](http://code.google.com/p/ptpv2d):

  - A further implementation
  - Unmaintained as well
- [linuxptp](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net):

  - A specific implementation for Linux
  - Maintained
  - Available on the CentOS repositories
  - Suggested by the RedHat documentation for both [RedHat 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_PTP_Using_ptp4l.html) and [RedHat 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Using_PTP.html)

My questions follow:

- Why does the RedHat documentation [suggest the use of linuxptp](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-Installing_PTP.html) for RedHat 6 (based on Linux kernel 2.6) despite [the linuxptp documentation says that a Linux kernel version 3.0 or newer is needed](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/) ?
- Which are differences between PTPd2 and Linuxptp in terms of reliability and timing accuracy ?

Comment: There are too many questions in one and is all overly broad. Please try to narrow down your question and be more specific, if you want to get good answer.

Comment: You are surely aware that Red Hat routinely backports kernel features and patches from newer kernels? [So they did for RHEL 6.4](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.4_Release_Notes/kernel.html), in which linuxptp was introduced.

Comment: Yes, I *supposed* it. What about the differences between linuxptp and PTPd2 ?